# How to check if all values of a C# dictionary are true?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary in C# with

```
var customDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
```

How can I check if all the values in a dictionary are `true` and return true only in that case?

Comment: `return !customDictionary.ContainsValue(false);` ??

Comment: Here is a solution you could use, getting the distinct values (True)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28087513/3200740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var allValuesAreTrue = customDicationary.Values.All(value => value);
```

Notice that the result is `true` if the dictionary is empty because "all values" are equal to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is with Linq. Check the values of the dictionary and see how many come back with true/false and continue based on that number.

```
public void Program()
{
    var customDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    customDictionary.Add("Apples are red", true);
    customDictionary.Add("Oranges are green", false);
    customDictionary.Add("Carrots are orange", true);
    
    bool allTrue = CheckDictionary(customDictionary);
    
    if(allTrue == true)
    {
        Console.Write("All True");
    }
    else{
        Console.Write("At least one false");
    }
}

public bool CheckDictionary(Dictionary<string, bool> dictToCheck)
{
    var test = dictToCheck.Where(x => x.Value == false);
    if (test.Count() == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output: At least one false